# Turn a page like a Book with UIView?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to switch between `UIViews` by making it look like you are turning a page in a book.

The `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp` is pretty close if I could get it to curl toward the Left or Right. Is this possible?

I have tried to use the `CATRansition` but none of the animation types come close to a page turning.

Any suggestions on how to create this page animation transition that would turn a page toward the left or right?

Answer (score 13):

**Edit (June 2012) :** It is now possible to use the native Apple implementation, check:

- [Page View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW3): Note that this is available since iOS 5.0.

Also check this other libs/methods:

- [Leaves](https://github.com/brow/leaves): Not so realistic, but really easy to use.
- [PageCurl](https://github.com/jemmons/PageCurl): Really nice effect, easy to use.
- [Implementing iBooks page curling using a conical deformation algorithm](http://wdnuon.blogspot.com/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html): Amazing, but it's just a proof of concept, difficult to expand.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the SDK that will do this for you. If you want this effect, you'll have to roll your own. "Classics" does a nice job with the page-flip animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this effect by changing the orientation of the UIViewController where the animation takes place.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please?