# How to Add Page Curl Effect to UIView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uiviewanimation, page-curl

I am working on an iOS Magazine App show the list of Magazines, i want to add the page curl effect to the cover page of the magazine (not the page curl animation just the static effect) as the below image describes. I search a lot but did't find any solution, your help will be appreciated Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn a page like a Book with UIView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477078/turn-a-page-like-a-book-with-uiview)

Comment: I just want to add the static effect to the UIView not the page animation