# iBook Image Curl Animation on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, animation, page-curl

I am working on `iPhone` app where i have 5-6 set of images. I want to change the image using page curl animation like `iBook`  where  user can swipe the page  as per the finger move with page curl animation. I want to implement same animation on iPhone.. Is there any way to do without using the private libraries or `UIPageViewController` or if there is any sample available to achieve this?

Apart from google search I am getting some kind of libaries such as:

Leaves

paperstack

XBPagecurl

pagecurling

Did not get much help.

Comment: see this http://www.iostute.com/2015/04/how-to-implement-partial-and-full-page.html

Comment: Thanks Anbu. I have looked into it . but this is happening on click of a button with predefined animation duration and time. I want this functionality as per the on user finger movement as implemented in  iBooks app.

Comment: customize your self add the code in gesture thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, do not go for exact solution, above solution will give you some idea and you can work on that and extent it. This way you learn more, the more you play. I have suggesting the blog please, go through it explore it.

[Turn a page like a Book with UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477078/turn-a-page-like-a-book-with-uiview)

Comment: Sanoj Kashyap, your link is not working, though I think your solution could be useful, I'd be happy to see it. Would be great if you could show it somewhere else.

Comment: @nickeyzzz This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477078/turn-a-page-like-a-book-with-uiview

Answer (score 2):

Add swipe gesture in your view like this

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(curlAnimation)];
[gesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[self.view1 addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

Make the curl animation using the following code snippet

```
- (void)curlAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         CATransition  * animation = [CATransition animation];
                         [animation setDelegate:self];
                         [animation setDuration:1.2f];
                         animation.startProgress = 0.0;
                         animation.endProgress   = 1;
                         [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                         [animation setType:@"pageCurl"];
                         [animation setSubtype:@"fromRight"];
                         [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
                         [animation setFillMode: @"extended"];
                         [animation setRemovedOnCompletion: NO];
                         [[self.view1 layer] addAnimation:animation
                                                            forKey:@"pageFlipAnimation"];
                     }
     ];
}
```

You can set the "fromLeft" in place of fromRight in this method `[animation setSubtype:@"fromRight"]`for animating from left to right

[image]

Happy coding..